# HTML5/JQueryMobile: Audio still playing if i click back button

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, html5-audio

i wrote a simple gallery which plays an audio file if available.
By clicking on the current pic it will simply jump back to index and stop playing the audio.
But if i click the back button on the browser the audio is still playing, even if i jump to another page with a simple  tag pointing to another page.

I think the problem is that jquery mobile is preloading pages and then showing it up at once after loading. I like the way jquery mobuile is preloading pages, but i would like to stop the audio if i click on the browsers back button.

I tried catching the back button with the $(window).unload() event, but it doesnt work. How can i totally unload the page (incl. audio) i want to leave?

Answer (score 0):

the unload event is handled differently in the various browsers, even between versions. You might also want to try the onbeforeunload event, as [suggested](http://api.jquery.com/unload/) on the jquery site:

> The exact handling of the unload event has varied from version to
>   version of browsers. For example, some versions of Firefox trigger the
>   event when a link is followed, but not when the window is closed. In
>   practical usage, behavior should be tested on all supported browsers,
>   and contrasted with the proprietary beforeunload event.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the `window`'s `hashchange` event. (Consult the [specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#event-hashchange) and [browser support](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2011/10/current-state-of-onhashchange-and-html5-history.html).)

Comment: hashchange is very interesting, but sadly my target browser (Android v4.x) doesnt support it (as long as i wanna use history api).